# Why my AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR not working properly?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import edu.self.debopam.android.asyncsycnhronize.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTaskCompleted{
    private Button btnInitiate;
    private Integer counter = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnInitiate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInitiate);
        btnInitiate.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.btnInitiate:
            initProcess();
            break;
        }

    }

    private void initProcess(){
        CounterAsyncTask1 counterAsyncTask1 = new CounterAsyncTask1(this);
        counterAsyncTask1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, counter);
        Log.i("initProcess", String.valueOf(counter));
        CounterAsyncTask2 counterAsyncTask2 = new CounterAsyncTask2();
        counterAsyncTask2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, counter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(Integer counterValue) {
        this.counter = counterValue;
        Log.i("Listener fired", String.valueOf(this.counter));
    }
}

class CounterAsyncTask1 extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>{

    OnTaskCompleted onTaskCompleted;

    public CounterAsyncTask1(OnTaskCompleted onTaskCompleted) {
        this.onTaskCompleted = onTaskCompleted;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... counters) {
        int counter = counters[0];
        for(counter = 1 ; counter <= 20 ; counter++){
            Log.i("CounterAsyncTask1", String.valueOf(counter));

        }
        return counter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        onTaskCompleted.onTaskCompleted(result);
    }

}


class CounterAsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>{


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... counters) {
        Log.i("initProcess", String.valueOf(counters[0]));
        int counter = counters[0];
        if(counter == 0)
            counter = 0;
        for(counter = 1 ; counter <= 100 ; counter++){
            Log.i("CounterAsyncTask2", String.valueOf(counter));
        }
        return counter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    }

}

interface OnTaskCompleted{
    void onTaskCompleted(Integer counterValue);
}
```

A little description about what I did. I have implemented a listener interface to set the value incremented by my first AsyncTask to be used by my secon AsyncTask. But still I see that my second AsyncTask is not working as it seems to be.

It seems I am missing out something. But couldn't find anything. No clues. Need help.

What is need to see is... after the counter for Asynctask is executed from 1 to 20 the next AsyncTask will start from 21 to 100.

Comment: For serial execution you may consider IntentService which will do the trick

Comment: You need to give more details.  What did you expect to see, and what do you actually see?  Because this code is really weird.